# Prevent comment author name from truncating

Tags: comments

In Drupal 8, long comment author names are truncated. These comments are from anonymous users. When I use the following preprocess function, Drupal responds with a HTTP 500 code, and I have to restore the site from backup.

```
function THEME_preprocess_username(&$vars) {
    $vars['name'] = check_plain($vars['name_raw']);
}
```

Is there another way of removing the truncation from author names in comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting an error because the check_plain() function doesn't exist in Drupal 8. Your error logs should be able to confirm that.

If you check the main [template_preprocess_username()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/template_preprocess_username/8.4.x) function where the truncated version of the name is set, you can see it uses [User::getDisplayName()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetDisplayName/8.4.x) and then truncates that.

So you could do this:

```
function THEME_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['account'] ?: new AnonymousUserSession();
  $variables['name'] = $account->getDisplayName();
}
```

If you want to keep with the check_plain() approach from your example, in Drupal 8 you can use [Html::escape()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Aescape/8.4.x).